# Maximize the window to the global menu of unity, using cairodock with unity?

Tags: unity, cairo-dock

hello i install cairodock 3 from

> ppa:cairo-dock-team

and select the beginning of secion of ubuntu " cairodock with unity"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIPs3.png

the problem is when i maximize window buttons (such as for eg close, minimize and maximiza) are not placed to the unity global menu. as you can see in the following pic

[image]

Comment: i use ubuntu 12.04 64bits

Comment: I know this problem, but unfortunately don't know any workaround or fix.